# How to use select option in the c:choose statement

Tags: html, jstl

I need to hide or show a combo depending on the value of the another combo, find my code below:

```
<TR>
    <TD>
        <span >Nazione</span><br>   
        <select name="residence_nation" class="form_textfield" id="residence_nation" style="width: 300px;">
            <c:forEach  var="iNation" items="${iListNation}" varStatus="rowCounter" >
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${iNation.id==iUserInfo.residence_nation}">
                        <option value="${iNation.id}" selected="selected">
                            <c:out value="${iNation.name}" />
                        </option>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <option value="${iNation.id}" >
                            <c:out value="${iNation.name}" />
                        </option>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </TD>
    <TD>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when
                test="${residence_nation.???==106}">
                <span >Provincia</span><br>
                <select name="residence_province" class="form_textfield" id="residence_province" style="width: 150px;">
                    <c:forEach  var="iProvince" items="${iListProvince}" varStatus="rowCounter" >
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${iProvince.id==iUserInfo.residence_province}">
                                <option value="${iProvince.id}">
                                    <c:out value="${iProvince.name}"/>
                                </option>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <option selected="selected" value="${iProvince.id}">
                                    <c:out value="${iProvince.name}" />
                                </option>
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <span>Provincia</span><br>
                <input name="residence_province" type="text" class="form_textfield" id="residence_province_input" size="55" value="
                <c:out value="${iUserInfo.residence_province_ext}" />
                " >                                             
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </TD>
</TR>
```

I don't know how to use residence_nation option value using JSTL.

```
 <c:when test="${residence_nation.???==106}">
```

find also my JavaScript

```
$("#residence_nation").change(function() 
         {
              if ($(this).val()!=106)
                  {
                  $('#residence_province').hide();                
                  $('#residence_city').hide();
                  $('#residence_province_input').show();


                  }else
                      {
                      $('#residence_province').show();                
                      $('#residence_city').show();
                      $('#residence_province_input').hide();

                      }
         });
```

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all I solved it in this way:

```
              <c:forEach  var="iNation" items="${iListNation}" varStatus="rowCounter" >
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${iNation.id==iUserInfo.residence_nation}">
                      <option value="${iNation.id}" selected="selected"><c:out value="${iNation.name}" /></option>

                      <c:set var="iStrNation" value="${iNation.name}" />

                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                      <option value="${iNation.id}" ><c:out value="${iNation.name}" /></option>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>                     
              </c:forEach>
        </select>

    <TD>    
                     <span >Provincia</span><br>
                    <c:set var="iStrItalia" value="Italia" />
                    <c:choose>
                      <c:when test="${iStrNation==iStrItalia}">                                                                             
                         <c:set var="iStyleProvInput"  value="display: none;" />
                         <c:set var="iStyleProvSelect" value="" />
                      </c:when>
                      <c:otherwise>                   
                       <c:set var="iStyleProvInput"  value="" />
                         <c:set var="iStyleProvSelect" value="display: none;" />
                      </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>


                     <input name="residence_province" type="text" class="form_textfield"  style ="${iStyleProvInput}" id="residence_province_input" size="55" value="<c:out value="${iUserInfo.residence_province_ext}" />" >                                               
                     <select name="residence_province" style ="${iStyleProvSelect}" class="form_textfield" id="residence_province" style="width: 150px;">
                        <c:forEach  var="iProvince" items="${iListProvince}" varStatus="rowCounter" >
                          <c:choose>
                          <c:when test="${iProvince.id==iUserInfo.residence_province}">
                             <option value="${iProvince.id}"><c:out value="${iProvince.name}"/></option>
                          </c:when>
                          <c:otherwise>
                             <option selected="selected" value="${iProvince.id}"><c:out value="${iProvince.name}" /> </option>
                          </c:otherwise>
                          </c:choose>                                           
                          </c:forEach>
                      </select> 
                    </TD>
```

Answer (score 0):

You really can't do that: JSTL and the expression language are evaluated server-side, not client side. If the `residence_nation` select form input element is changed by the client in their browser that change is not available to the expression language in the JSP page.

For this you will need to use Javascript: jQuery is generally my library of choice. There are a million jQuery tutorials on using the `select` element: the canonical one is [here](http://api.jquery.com/change/). You can bind a function that hides/shows the right option when the value of the `residence_nation` field is changed.

Comment: Hi Femi, I already did it , but I also need to show/hide it "by default" when I load the page....

Comment: Well, if you have javascript logic on the client side bound to the `change` event then maybe you could just trigger a change event on page load.

Comment: I also used style property to hide the box but it doesn't work

Comment: Ah. Well, maybe you want to do this: `<c:when
                         test="${iUserInfo.residence_nation == 106}">` because there is really no way to refer to an HTML `select`'s value in JSTL.

Comment: I already tried it , It works just for the first time.. java script that hide the box doesn't work

Comment: Oh. Then you probably have an error in your Javascript. Post it and we can take a look.

Comment: find it below :$("#residence_nation").change(function() 
   {
           if ($(this).val()!=106)
            {
            $('#residence_province').hide();            
            $('#residence_city').hide();
            $('#residence_province_input').show();
            
            
            }else
             {
             $('#residence_province').show();            
             $('#residence_city').show();
             $('#residence_province_input').hide();
             
             }
   });